# The type 'StateNotifierProvider' is declared with 2 type parameters, but 1 type arguments were given

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

In the context of a Flutter 2.0.5 app whose state I'd like to manage with Riverpod, I thought I can declare a `StateNotifierProvider` like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';


final counterProvider = StateNotifierProvider<CounterStateNotifier>((ref) => CounterStateNotifier());

class CounterStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<int> {
  CounterStateNotifier([int count = 0]) : super(count);

  void increment() => state++;
}
```

But Android Studio (and later the Dart compiler as well) complains about the line where I declare the `counterProvider` variable:

> The type 'StateNotifierProvider' is declared with 2 type parameters, but 1 type arguments were given.

Removing the `<CounterStateNotifier>` type parameter in `StateNotifierProvider<CounterStateNotifier>` removes the error. However, attempting to read the provider and call its `increment` method (setting `() => context.read(counterProvider).increment()` as the `onPressed` of an `ElevatedButton`, then pressing the button) gives the following runtime error:

```
'increment'
method not found
Receiver: 0
Arguments: []
```

Why is `context.read(counterProvider)` returning the `int` state instead of the notifier? And what is the reason behind the type parameter error mentioned in the first part of my question?

---

I should mention that I'm running my app on the web (with `flutter run -d Chrome`).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As of Riverpod 0.14.0, State is the default value exposed by StateNotifierProvider.

The syntax for declaring your StateNotifierProvider is now as follows:

```dart
final counterProvider = StateNotifierProvider<CounterStateNotifier, int>((ref) => CounterStateNotifier());
```

Accessing functions now requires adding `.notifier` (accessing the StateNotifier itself):

```dart
context.read(counterProvider.notifier).increment();
```

And like you've noticed, you now access the state like so:

```dart
final count = context.read(counterProvider);
```

More on the changes [here](https://riverpod.dev/docs/migration/0.13.0_to_0.14.0).

Comment: Thank you!!! Why isn't this on the `StateNotifierProvider` class docs. I've been struggling for about a day trying to get this to work. https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/StateNotifierProvider-class.html

Comment: Edit: Just noticed the docs have been updated in master, I guess the next time it's published the docs will have the new API.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use dynamic to accept any type if value for the StateNotifierProvider

```
final modelProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<ModelClassName, dynamic>(
        (ref) => ModelClassName());
```