# How can I use riverpod's statenotifier for handling a form?

Tags: flutter, hook, riverpod

I'm trying to use StateNotifier to handle a form but watching the stateNotifierProvider, I get the object I'm trying to update instead of the provider.

Here is my implementation:

```
final profileCreationFormNotifierProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider((ref) => ProfileCreationFormNotifier());

class ProfileCreationFormNotifier extends StateNotifier<ProfileModel> {
  ProfileCreationFormNotifier()
      : super(
          ProfileModel(
            city: '',
            country: '',
            firstname: '',
            lastname: '',
            pictureUrl: '',
            username: '',
            gender: '',
          ),
        );

  void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    state = state.copyWith(firstname: firstname);
  }

  void setLatstname(String lastname) {
    state.copyWith(lastname: lastname);
  }

  void setUsername(String username) {
    state.copyWith(username: username);
  }

  void setGender(String gender) {
    state.copyWith(gender: gender);
  }
}
```

Then in a Consumer widget I try to call the methods to update a field on the form like this

```
Consumer(
  builder:
      (BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch, Widget? child) {
    return CustomTextField(
      controller: usernameFieldController,
      hintText: 'Username',
      isEmail: false,
      onSave: (value) {
        context
            .read(profileCreationFormNotifierProvider)
            .setUsername(value);
      },
      onValidate: (value) => validator(value!, "Username"),
      secured: false,
    );
  },
),
```

I get the following error:

> Class 'ProfileModel' has no instance method 'setUsername'. Receiver:
> Instance of 'ProfileModel' Tried calling: setUsername("qsqsqsq")

What I'm I doing wrong here?

I'm using hook_riverpod version: "0.14.0+2"
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Riverpod 0.14.0, State is the default value exposed by StateNotifierProvider.

Change:

```dart
context
  .read(profileCreationFormNotifierProvider)
  .setUsername(value);
```

to:

```dart
context
  .read(profileCreationFormNotifierProvider.notifier)
  .setUsername(value);
```

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67234289/7259858).

More on the changes [here](https://riverpod.dev/docs/migration/0.13.0_to_0.14.0).

Comment: thank you a lot! I wished I spent more time on the documentation