# Flutter riverpod 0.14.0 invoke function in state notifier

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I've recently migrated to riverpod 14

I've change my provider so it now takes the generic types

```
class Counter extends StateNotifier<int> {
  Counter() : super(0);

  void increment() => state++;
}

final counterProvider = StateNotifierProvider<Counter,int>((ref) {
  return Counter();
});
```

Specifically...
`StateNotifierProvider<Counter,int>`

But when I try to invoke the function `increment`

I get "The getter 'increment' isn't defined for the type 'int'"

```
class _LoginFormState extends State<LoginForm> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => context.read(counterProvider).increment,
      child: Text('increment'),
    );
  }
}
```

Not sure what I need to change in order to invoke `increment`

Any help welcome!

Thanks

Comment: just add .notifier like this `context.read(counterProvider.notifier).increment()`

Comment: Yep! - This is the correct answer.
It was in the migration documentation as well. I just missed it.. flips table.

to obtain the StateNotifier, you should now read myProvider.notifier instead of just myProvider:


Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The type 'StateNotifierProvider' is declared with 2 type parameters, but 1 type arguments were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67233449/the-type-statenotifierprovider-is-declared-with-2-type-parameters-but-1-type)

Comment: Yes it does - I was trying to set it as the answer - but could not see how to.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this syntax

```
context.read(counterProvider.notifier).increment()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).